# How to unit test binary string representations of signed integers with various lengths in ruby?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing

I wanted to write a test to verify binary string representations of signed integers with various lengths. I do not know how to compute the expected values for random positive and negative integers represented as binary strings, with different binary lengths (8,16,32, 64). So far I have a test that just prints out the values for inspection.

Below are the test (which just prints out the result, with no assertions) and the function:

```
# test

def test_binary_string_with_length
  10.times do 
    n = -rand(128)
    puts "n: #{n} -> bin8: #{binary_string_with_length(n, 8)}"

    n = rand(256)
    puts "n: #{n} -> bin8: #{binary_string_with_length(n, 8)}"

    n = -rand(2 ** 15) 
    puts "n: #{n} -> bin16: #{binary_string_with_length(n, 16)}"

    n = rand(2 ** 16) 
    puts "n: #{n} -> bin16: #{binary_string_with_length(n, 16)}"

    n = -rand(2 ** 31)
    puts "n: #{n} -> bin32: #{binary_string_with_length(n, 32)}"

    n = rand(2 ** 32)
    puts "n: #{n} -> bin32: #{binary_string_with_length(n, 32)}"

    n = -rand(2 ** 63)
    puts "n: #{n} -> bin64: #{binary_string_with_length(n, 64)}"

    n = rand(2 ** 64)
    puts "n: #{n} -> bin64: #{binary_string_with_length(n, 64)}"
  end
end

# function

def binary_string_with_length(n, int_length_in_bits)
  pack = 'Q' # default is 64 bit
  case int_length_in_bits
  when 8
    pack = 'C'
  when 16
    pack = 'S'
  when 32
    pack = 'L'
  when 64
    pack = 'Q'
  end
  sprintf('%b', [n].pack(pack).unpack(pack)[0])
end
```

How do I write assertions to validate that each string representation is correct?

Comment: Well, I'd start with learning how to compute binary representations of positive and negative numbers. Then implement your conversion. And test against ruby's logic. Simple as that.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev - I will clarify my question - I know how to compute binary representations of positive and negative numbers - the problem is specific to ruby, being dynamically typed, that it does not internally have a specific size (in bytes) for an integer. The size itself seems to grow with the integer (integers can be arbitrarily large, and ruby grows to support them limited only by memory). The way to compute the binary representation for various sizes **is** what I do in the function above. How do I now *verify* its accuracy?

Comment: Put the clarification into your question, inserting it where you would have if you'd entered it initially. _Don't use "updated" or "edited" tags_. We can tell what was added if necessary. This way everyone will see the information without having to read every comment.

Comment: @theTinMan - I would like to do that too - I have done that in the past, but sometimes responders don't like that, since their older answers can get out of sync with the question - by having a 'revision history' in the question, users can map responses over time better.

Comment: All questions and answers have a built-in revision system that is automatically applied, which is why using "edited" and "updated" tags are NOT wanted. Access to that revision history is based on a users reputation. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges. Also read http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/127655/153968

Answer (score 6):

Don't test random arbitrary values in your unit tests. Pick a set of inputs to test against their known expected outputs. Include edge cases. Add additional test cases as they come up in production to insure you don't introduce regressions.

In the simplest terms, build a hash of inputs to expected values, and then iterate over the hash and assert that the actual value equals the expected value.

Comment: Yes, I agree - with specific inputs including edge cases, this would work. I prefer to use random values whenever possible, though. I think one trend in testing encourages random value testing, precisely because we cannot trust ourselves to anticipate the right set of cases (Netflix's chaos monkey is an example: http://techblog.netflix.com/2012/07/chaos-monkey-released-into-wild.html)

Comment: @Anand Using random inputs and *computing* the expected outputs defeats the point of writing tests. Now, you have two implementations that you're testing against each other, instead of testing one implementation against known good values. Now, your tests need tests.

Comment: @Anand That said, there is a time and place for randomized testing, and it isn't unit testing. Chaos Monkey operates *orders of magnitude* higher up the stack than simple unit tests. Randomized testing is a good way of insuring you *miss* the edge cases that are the most valuable cases to cover.

Comment: I hear you - and I would tend to agree, in most cases. But I still feel there are some scenarios in unit testing that could benefit from randomized testing. This example here seems right on the fence :-)

Comment: @Anand I completely disagree. There is generally no value to randomized inputs in unit testing, and *absolutely* no value in this case. You need about 12 cases to be completely confident in this method, and using randomized ones offers *no* additional confidence.

Comment: Edge cases are where testing lives or dies. Know your boundaries and test them aggressively. Examine the code to see where it branches and exercise every branch. Use a coverage tool if you need to if that helps ensure you don't miss things. Randomized testing (e.g. fuzzing) is an important part of testing, but it's not the first approach you should take. You *need* known-good outputs that exercise all of your boundary conditions.

Comment: @meagar There are several benefits I have personally experienced in using randomized inputs over only using static inputs in unit testing. Anyway, I don't want to debate here - maybe I'll summarize somewhere else and share a link at some time.

Comment: @tadman I agree - I am only suggesting randomized testing in addition to static testing including all conceivable edge cases (coverage is moot here as I am doing test first development) - my question was about *how* to do that (randomized testing) in this case, but somehow this has turned into a debate of whether or not we *should* do randomized testing :-)

Comment: Either you're talking about fuzzing, something done to shake out bugs by throwing in unexpected data, or you're talking about what meagar has already pointed out: Writing test code that re-implements the desired behaviour to verify the desired behaviour. You're comparing implementation A to implementation B which, while useful in some cases, is not how you test your first implementation.

Comment: @Anand Sometimes I do generate lots of random data, run it through a tested, working version of a method, and freeze the output (e.g. YAML or JSON structure). Then I build tests around that to avoid regressions when doing things like optimizing the code. This avoids double-implementing, you're just comparing your current implementation to your historical one on the basis that the historical one has already been proven correct.

Comment: @tadman I like that approach - and I agree with the point (and meagar's related point) about the risks of double-implementing or computing the expected result in the random case.